# Responsive Justified image gallery with Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, gallery

I'm trying to make an image gallery, based on this example :

```css
body { margin: 0; background: #333; }
header { 
  padding: .5vw;
  font-size: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; 
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
}
header div { 
  -webkit-box-flex: auto;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  flex: auto; 
  width: 200px; 
  margin: .5vw; 
}
header div img { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto; 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  header div { margin: 0; }
  header { padding: 0; }
  
}
```

```html
<header>
<div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-1.jpg" alt></div>
<div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-2.jpg" alt></div>
<div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-3.jpg" alt></div>
<div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-4.jpg" alt></div>
<div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-5.jpg" alt></div>
  <!-- images placed inside block elements to deal with a Firefox rendering bug affecting  scaled flexbox images -->
</header>
```

All my images are 200x200px, it works like a charm, but I need to replace the last line with the same fixed original image size justified on the left.

I've tried adding an `::after` element filling the blank space, as suggested on other answers, but I didn't succeed.

Ultimately, I'm thinking about adding fake images with no display based on media queries and the number of images per row, using Javascript.

Is there any other better way to achieve this?

My code :

```
.c-gallery {
    font-size: 0;
    max-width: 1600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    a {
        flex: auto;
        width: 150px;
        margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
          img {
              height: auto;
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: provide your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following. It uses the CSS grid.
By playing with `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);` you can change the amount of columns.

```css
body { margin: 0; background: #333; }
header { 
  padding: .5vw;
  font-size: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);
  grid-gap: .5vw
}

header div img { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto; 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  header div { margin: 0; }
  header { padding: 0; }
}
```

```html
<header>
<div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-1.jpg" alt></div>
<div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-2.jpg" alt></div>
<div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-3.jpg" alt></div>
<div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-4.jpg" alt></div>
<div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-5.jpg" alt></div>
  <!-- images placed inside block elements to deal with a Firefox rendering bug affecting  scaled flexbox images -->
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you SuperDJ, yes I thought about it, but I didn't want to use CSS Grid for compatibility concerns... However, it's true if there is no other way, I could consider using it with @support verification and then use a centered flexbox as a fallback (still not as ulgy as the unjustifed last row)

Comment: @NightCoffeeLover I don't think compatibility is that much of a concern unless you want to support < IE 9 https://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: Yep, best solution! Made it with some hack to make it responsive (with object-fit on <a> tag)  and a flexbox fallback, thanks SuperDJ! :)

Comment: @NightCoffeeLover depending on what you mean with responsive you could also use `repeat(3, minmax(200px, 1fr))`. `1fr` being that it scales to max width while 3 columns remain. On the other hand the column will never get smaller than `200px`